# Group HashMap items according to a specific key

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap, grouping

I have a ArrayList>> which holds certain key-value entries. Like:-

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("NewId", newId);
map.put("Title", title);
map.put("Description", description);

myList.add(map);
```

"NewId" can be similar for multiple entries.

Also I have an Array of colors:-

```
String[] colors = new String[]{"#1F1A17", "#62934D", "#F9B03F", "#7959BC", "#74B8DE", "#E65641", "#7CC8BB", "#D7CE5D", "#D6BE95", "#B694D1"};
```

I want to now group all the entries with same "NewId" together and assign them the first color, other entries with next similar "NewId" with the second color and so on till items with first 10 same "NewId" get assigned with their respective colors.

eg:- before grouping

```
NewId  Title  Description
 101   title1  des1
 102   title2  des2
 103   title3  des3 
 101   title4  des4
 102   title5  des5
 103   title6  des6
```

after grouping

```
NewId  Title  Description
 101   title1  des1  ------> color1
 101   title4  des4  ------> color1
 102   title2  des2  ------> color2
 102   title5  des5  ------> color2
 103   title3  des3  ------> color3
 103   title6  des6  ------> color3
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need a pretty impressive loop. Advanced for loops are really going to help. If I understand you right, you want something like this

```
int i = 0; //Or whatever the starting id number is
int j = 0; //For managing the color assigning
//If you want a new hash map Map<String, String> colorsMap = new HashMap<>();    


for (HashMap<String, String> loopMap : myList) {
     while (i < colors.length) {
         if (loopMap.containsKey("" + i) {
             loopMap.put("" + i + "color", colors[j]);
             //Or if you want to make a new HashMap: colorsMap.put("" + i, colors[j]);
         }
         i++; //Now start with next id entry
         j++; //And next color
     }
     i = 0; //Or starting id num
     j = 0; //Starting color index
} 
//If you are making a new hash map: myList.add(colorsMap);
```

I would personally use a class to put the data, title, description, and color data together, it will make things a lot simpler. And it would let you add methods to better

Answer (score 1):

you can add a custom list class:

```
public class MyList {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public boolean add(HashMap<String, String> map) {
        return list.add(map);
    }

    public void setColor(String newId, String color) {
        for (HashMap<String, String> m : list)
            if (m.containsKey(newId))
                m.put("color", color);
    }

    public String getGroupKey(String key, int i) {      
        ArrayList<String> uniqeList = getUniqKeyList(key);
        Collections.sort(uniqeList);
        return uniqeList.get(i);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getUniqKeyList(String key){
        ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
        for (HashMap<String, String> m : list)
            if(!l.contains(m.get(key)))
                l.add(m.get(key));
        return l;
    }
}
```

and in main every thing is clear and simple :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyList myList = new MyList();
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("NewId", newId);
        map.put("Title", title);
        map.put("Description", description);
        myList.add(map);

        String[] colors = new String[]{"#1F1A17", "#62934D","#B694D1"};

        int i=0;
        while (true) {
                    if(i == colors.length) 
                            break;
            String s =  myList.getGroupKey("NewId", i);
            if(s == null)
                break;
            else 
                myList.setColor(s, colors[i++]);
        }       
    }
```

Comment: My newId comes from a JSON response. How do I group the similar ids first? Wont your solution take all ids into the array

Comment: How can I pass this list to a ListAdapter?

Comment: how can this for a simple List?

Comment: Iam trying to add the list to display a ListView

Comment: Still get the same Error

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, instead of using an `Arraylist<HashMap<string, string>>` you use a `HashMap<string, List<MyCustomObject>>`. The `CustomObject` class will hold attributes `NewId`, `Title` and `Description`. The Key for this hashmap is the NewId attribute. This is important because you are assigning colors per value for NewId. Using this approach, you can assign one color per entry in your map.